# After switching from CMK to default E@R for a DDB table, can my services still be able to access the data in Dynamo DB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kms

Lets consider the following chain of events:

1. Currently the DDB table uses default E@R provided by DynamoDB.
2. I switched the E@R to use a customer managed key I created in KMS with required permissions.
3. There has been data added to the table after the E@R is enabled using CMK.
4. Due to some reason, I need to switch the E@R back to the default provided by DynamoDB.

Q: My question is, would my services still be able to access the data added in step 3(basically the data encrypted using CMK) when I have switched the E@R back to DynamoDB default and removed the access for services from the CMK created(or just deleted the CMK)?

I understand that DDB tables always have E@R enabled. Its up to us whether we want to use the default key provided by Dynamo DB or AWS or use our own customer managed key(CMK).
In the normal scenario, using a CMK is working as expected for E@R in DDB but I am unsure of the edge case mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have no issues. DynamoDB uses envelope style encryption in which you only encrypt the data key, and not the data. That's why changing keys includes no downtime.

More here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/encryption.howitworks.html